# Last-Modified header is M2.4.3 upgrade date

Tags: magento2, nginx, varnish, apache

We have recently upgraded our M2.4.3 version and have noticed that the last modified header for all our web pages is now fixed at the exact upgrade date of our store across all web pages even newly created pages.

I believe m2.4.3 is now running out of /pub directory

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

We run Apache with Varnish and Nginx SSL termination (engintron)

We did not have this issue proper to upgrade

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this was... after upgraded the whole of our M2.4.3 frontend was stuck at the last modification date of index.php. This was returning constant 304 from googlebot

Stripped Modified-since, and last-modified headers using varnish to solve the issue.

I am not sure what correct behaviour is for magento using last-mod headers.